# How can I delete matrix rows when contained in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, octave

As always I realise this is a simple question but being relatively new to the power of Octave I am struggling to get my head around this. I have a cell array A, which contains vectors. I wish to delete the last two values from each vector and finally append a vector contained within another cell array to each. Here is a minimal example:

```
A = {[1 2 11 12] [1 2 11 12] [1 2 11 12]}
A = 
{
[1,1] =
      1        2        11        12
[1,2] =
      1        2        11        12
[1,3] =
      1        2        11        12
}
B = {[3 4 5] [3 4 5] [3 4 5]}
B = 
{
[1,1] =
      3        4        5
[1,2] =
      3        4        5
[1,3] =
      3        4        5
}
```

Thus I want to end up with:

```
C =
{
[1,1] =
      1        2        3       4       5
[1,2] =
      1        2        3       4       5
[1,3] =
      1        2        3       4       5
}
```

Any pointers to documentation on this etc. would be great.

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `cellfun`:

```
C = cellfun( @(x, y) [x(1:end-2) y], A, B, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: @user1912925 Also, if all cells contain the same amount of elements, consider using a matrix instead. It is much easier to manipulate.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. @EitanT the reason for the use of a cell array is twofold: 1) it is the product of a dataload loop (I was told a cell array was best for this) and 2) the data has a variable size of elements, otherwise as you say matrices would be more appropriate.